# Downloading multiple files in a queue with a browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser, dom-events

I need to download multiple files from a server, and I'm not allowed to download them in parallel so I need to queue them up. I don't have access to the download server so I can only work with the browser.

Is there any sort of API for detecting when a download finishes? I tired looking around but couldn't find anything. Only supporting chrome would be fine, but also supporting Firefox is preferred obviously.

Answer (score 0):

There different solutions.
You can do this via Jquery Script or Browser Plugins.

Both are fast and easy to use.

Extension: 
http://www.flashget.com/doc/addjob.htm

Jquery
http://eysermans.com/post/sequentially-download-multiple-files-with-jquery

Hope that helps,

Comment: I'd prefer not having to rely on an extension since it's not provided right out of the box. The jquery solution seems to fire them off all at once, or am I wrong?